# Convert List of object arrays to list of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is there any Utility function in Java to convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<Object>`

Comment: describe you question properly

Comment: The question is ambiguous: what should happen if an array contains two or more elements? Please provide an example.

Comment: What would you expect as a result from that function?

Comment: No, there is no such method available. Either iterate over the list and each array and add the entries into a new list or use one of the fancy Java 8 Streams.

Comment: @rams, feel free to review the answers and accept the one the best answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write one yourself:

```
public static<T> List<T> append (List<T[]> input) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T[] subarr : input) {
        if(subarr != null) {
            int n = subarr.length;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                res.add(subarr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The function appends the different arrays and `null` arrays are ignored, `null` elements are however not. Thus if the input is `[null,[a,b],[null,null],[c,null,d],null]`. The output is `[a,b,null,null,c,null,d]`.

Comment: `new List<T>()`? Since when can you instantiate an interface? But besides that, I like that you're checking for null.

Comment: @Tom: True, modified it. In C#, `List<T>` is a class :(. Sometimes one starts mixing up std-libs... :s

Comment: Why allow null arrays?  Null arrays seem likely to indicate a bug earlier in the program...?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: `null` arrays are ignored. Simply because some people see them as zero-length arrays. It is of course arbitrary. But in case `null` shouldn't be allowed, one can simply remove the `if` clause.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no method that does this directly for you. You can write a nested for loop or use the flatMap of the stream API as follows:

```
List<Object> flat = objArrs.stream()
                           .flatMap(Stream::of)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

Why don't you just write the function yourself? It would probably be faster than asking this question and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can do it with Streams :

```
List<Object[]> list = ...
List<Object> l = list.stream()
                     .flatMap(arr -> Stream.of(arr))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, there is no utility and creating one yourself wouldn't be hard, for example using *old school* for loops:

```
public List<Object> flatten( List<Object[]> source )
{
    // if ( source == null ) return null; // which check you use it up to you
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if ( source == null ) return result; // Personally I like this check

    for ( Object[] array: source )
    {
        if ( array == null ) continue; // skip nulls
        for ( Object object: array )
        {
            result.add(object);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```